# Angular ngRepeat increase $index and render view accordingly.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider that I've got two views, view1 and view2.

I am getting an array from an API in View1. From there, I am trying to go to view2 and dynamically render view2 for as many times as there are objects in the array by tracking by $index. (That's what is the expected behavior)

In the **HTML**, i am going from view1 to view2 in the following manner:

View1:

```
    <div ng-repeat="factor in vm.testDetails.factor track by $index">
          <button ui-sref="app.factor_stans({factorName: factor.name, factorId: factor._id })" class="factorNamePress" > {{factor.name}} </button>
    </div>
```

View2:

```
<div ng-click="vm.goToPrevDim()">Go to previous dimension</div>

<div ng-click="vm.goToNextDim()">Go to next dimension</div>


<label for="low_stan">Number of stens in low</label>
<input type="number" name="low_stan" ng-model="vm.low_stan">
</div>

<button ng-click="vm.fillStans()"> Submit Query</button>

<h1>Low Stan Fills</h1>
<div ng-include="vm.stanFills.lowStanFills">
 <!--This contains some input felds that I want to attach with this given url --> 
</div>
```

I'll only post the relevant parts of the **controller** below:

```
vm.fillStans      = fillStans;
vm.goToPrevDim    = goToPrevDim;
vm.goToNextDim    = goToNextDim;

function selectedItemChange(item) {
          console.log("This is the item that I am gonna send to the backend");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
          AdminService.getDetailsOfOneTest(item.value).then(function (response) {
            console.log("This is the details of the test");
            vm.testDetails = response.data;

            vm.finalObj = vm.testDetails.factor[vm.dimensionIndex.index]
            console.log(vm.testDetails);
            console.log("End of details of test");
            goToNextDim();
            goToPrevDim();
            // $location.path('app.factor_stans');




          })

       }





function goToNextDim() {





      vm.dimensionIndex.index =  vm.dimensionIndex.index + 1;
    vm.finalObj = vm.testDetails .factor[vm.dimensionIndex.index];
    console.log(vm.finalObj);

  }



  function goToPrevDim() {




  vm.dimensionIndex.index =  vm.dimensionIndex.index - 1;
     vm.finalObj = vm.testDetails .factor[vm.dimensionIndex.index];
     console.log(vm.finalObj);





  }
```

**Expected behavior** is that from view2, it should be able to go to next factor or previous factor as I click on the button, but it is not going.

I have spent an entire day trying to solve this problem and I am drawing a blank. Please look into it and see if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation 
`JSFiddle:` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3471/). See if it solves your problem.